# Proof that Distinguished Open Set is an Affine Variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm trying to understand the proof in Mumford's Red Book that a distinguished open set of an affine variety is itself an affine variety. I've attached an image of the proof, and cannot seem understand why the image of the morphism from E* $ \rightarrow $ E has image $E_{f_1}$. In particular, how would one show that $1=f_1(x_1,...,x_n){x_{n+1}} \iff f_1(x_1,...,x_n) \neq 0$?
[image: mumford proof]

Comment: I can't read the proof as the image's resolution is too low.

Comment: Sorry, see if the updated image is any better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x = (x_1, \dots, x_{n+1}) \in \Sigma^*$ then $f_1(x_1, \dots, x_n)x_{n+1} = f(\alpha(x))x_{n+1} = 1$, so $f(\alpha(x)) \neq 0$ and hence $\alpha(x) \in \Sigma_f$. You can reverse this: if $(x_1, \dots, x_n) \in \Sigma_f$ then $f(x_1, \dots, x_n) \neq 0$ so there is a unique $x_{n+1} \in k^*$ such that $f(x_1, \dots, x_n)x_{n+1} = 1$ and the point $(x_1, \dots, x_{n+1})$ lies in $\Sigma^*$.

The lessons are that being nonzero in a field is the same as having an inverse, and to write everything out. This $\Leftrightarrow$ with no quantifiers makes me nervous. Keep the example of $X = \mathbb{A}^1$ with coordinate $x$ and $f_1 = x$ in mind. The picture is nice.